# Quais os principais padrões de projetos em NODEJS para desenvolvimento Web?

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Nodejs e preciso saber quais os principais padrões de projeto para Desenvolvimento Web em Nodejs.

Comment: Depende, fala de Web? Porque Node.js é uma ferramenta que serve para vários propósitos diferentes, não só Web.

Comment: Aqui há uma matéria bem bacana falando sobre os principais Design Patterns. http://nomadev.com.br/node-js-design-patterns-fundamentais-padr%C3%B5es-de-projeto/

Comment: Editei a pergunta. O foco é desenvolvimento Web !

Comment: Node.js não tem padrões específicos web, quem tem padrão é o Express, que usa Middleware que possui uma ferramenta facilitadora chamada express-generator, claro que devem existir implementações como MVC para usar em projetos Web, mas não tem ligação direta com o Node.js (apesar de obviamente fazerem uso dele), creio que o principal seja Middleware mesmo e mesmo que tenha algum framework que use Node.js para web  além do Express é provavel que também faça uso do Express como base ou se não fizer é provável que nem seja tão popular. Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/express/info